# Building an executable with OpenGL

Tags: ros, opengl, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a C++ program which requires glut and OpenGL to run.
If I was compiling without ROS, I would add the compiler flags -lGL and -lGLU. However when using rosmake and CMakeLists I obviously can't.

How can I make rosmake link to external system libraries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11293/building-an-executable-with-opengl/) by [hanneshdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1113/hanneshdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're writing a library which will be used from another package in your manifest.xml you should export required flags, e.g.
<export>
<cpp lflags="-lGL -lglut" />
</export>

For the a binary in your CMakeLists.txt you could add
target_link_libraries(yourprogram GL glut)

or

link_libraries(GL glut)

---

Originally posted by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) with karma: 544 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3